# angular 2 create custom variables to perfomm CRUD on specified url

Tags: angular, crud, angular2-services, angular-http

below is a model which includes some http request. My question is can i hab services instantiated through instantiating a new class object?

```
export class DbHttp {

    private path:string;

    constructor(private path:string, private customService:CustomService){}

    create(data:Object):Observable<Response>{
        return this.customService.create(this.path, data)
    }

    getAll():Observable<Response>{
        return this.customService.getAll(this.path)
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is a shortcut to perform http request on customized url. ideally the syntax should be something like this

```
public dbAccessTodo = this.service.access('todo')
//access is a method which returns an object with builtin CRUD functions for a Base_Url+'todo'

create(data){
  this.dbAccessTodo.create(data)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

I created services like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
    private endPoint = 'Orders';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    get(id: string) {
        return this.http
            .get(`'${this.endPoint}/${id}`, { body: '' })
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

And to change the base Url of my api I use a CustomRequestOptions

```
export class CustomRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
    merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {
        ...
        options.url = '<%= API_BASE_URL %>' + options.url;
        var result = super.merge(options);
        result.merge = this.merge;
        return result;
}
```

Hope this helps, otherwise, please explain your question in more detail.